# Implicitly typed local variables must be initialised

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to dynamically put a condition like this :-

```
var data;
if(employeId != 0) {
 data = (from a in ctx.tblTO1
             join b in ctx.tblTO2
                    on a.Company equals b.Company
                    where a.Id == b.Id &&
                    a.employeeId == employeeId
                    select new { a = a, b = b }).ToList();
}else{
     data = (from a in ctx.tblTO1
                 join b in ctx.tblTO2
                        on a.Company equals b.Company
                        where a.Id == b.Id &&
                        a.Cat == cats
                        select new { a = a, b = b }).ToList();
}
```

The result of the above expression is of Anonymous Type. So i am not able to declare it & the 1st line gives error. `Implicitly typed local variables must be initialised`.

What is the way to solve this? Can we use a separate function, but then what will be the functions return type?

Comment: You might get away by declaring data as dynamic. Or just declare data as a list of Tuple<object,object>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, of course `var data;` makes no sense.

You could define a type with the appropriate fields to be the element type. This is particularly useful if the same type comes up more than once.

You could also use `?:` where you here use `if…else`:

```
var data = (employeeId != 0)
  ? (from a in ctx.tblTO1
     join b in ctx.tblTO2
      on a.Company equals b.Company
      where a.Id == b.Id &&
        a.employeeId == employeeId
        select new { a = a, b = b }).ToList()
  : (from a in ctx.tblTO1
     join b in ctx.tblTO2
       on a.Company equals b.Company
       where a.Id == b.Id &&
         a.Cat == cats
         select new { a = a, b = b }).ToList();
```

But perhaps the clearest is to modify a query for just what differs with each case:

```
var query = from a in ctx.tblTO1
            join b in ctx.tblTO2
            on a.Company equals b.Company
            where a.Id == b.Id
            select new { a = a, b = b };

if (employeeId != 0)
  query = query.Where(i => i.a.employeeId == employeeId);
else
   query = query.Where(i => i.a.Cat == cats);
var data = query.ToList();
```

This has the advantage of making the difference between the two cases clearer in the code. Separating out the `ToList()` also has the advantage of making it clearer if you change your code in such a way as to no longer need it.

Comment: The 2nd code block looks good. I will go with 2nd code snippet.!

Comment: Yeah, that's the best way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a DTO class instead of the anonymous type. Resharper can make that transformation for you. Or, you can use the conditional operator to allow type inference to work here:

```
var data = employeId != 0 ? (query1) : (query2);
```

That's not going to be pretty.

There's another hack for this:

```
var data = new [] { new { a = 0, b = 0 } }.ToList();
```

This creates a dummy object to make `var` type inference work. You probably should not do this...

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = (from a in ctx.tblTO1
                 join b in ctx.tblTO2
                        on a.Company equals b.Company
                        where a.Id == b.Id &&
                        ((a.Cat == cats && employeId==0)||
                         (a.employeeId == employeeId))
                        select new { a = a, b = b }).ToList();
```

Comment: That's a valid solution but it probably will not be able to use any indexes.

Comment: It will able to use indexes. I don't see any reason why it can't.

Comment: That `||` usually leads to indexes not being used in SQL Server. An index cannot be used to seek on two different columns.

Comment: @usr would the `||` logic be passed all the way to the produced SQL here, rather than either the fact that `employeeId == 0` is always false or always true for a give invocation being used to simplify the code used to either one branch or the other?

Comment: @JonHanna no LINQ provider that I know of performs this kind of simplification. This should reach SQL Server as something like `@p0 = 0 AND ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the query as follows

```
(from a in ctx.tblTO1
         join b in ctx.tblTO2
                on a.Company equals b.Company
                where a.Id == b.Id &&
                ( (employeId != 0 && a.employeeId == employeeId) || (a.Cat == cats))
                select new { a = a, b = b }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`var data;` cannot possibly work, as `var` is only ever resolved against the initialiser, not any subsequent assignments.

You have two major options: either you can stop using anonymous types, or you can make sure you have an initialiser. The first of these can look like:

```
class MyClass {
    public T01 a;
    public T02 b;
}
```

Now, you can use `List<MyClass>`.

The second of these can be broken down into two sub-options: you can either re-work your existing logic to fit in a single expression, or use a dummy value for initialisation.

The first of these can look like `var data = condition ? query1 : query2;`.

The second of these can look like `var data = true ? null : query1;`, where `query1` never actually gets evaluated, it's just used to determine the type of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot only declare a variable implicitely, without giving it any value. 
When you write:

```
var a = "foo";
```

that means, that you have a variable of type `string`, not just a variable that you gave a value of string. Compiler need to know what the type exactly is, even if the type is implied from the usage.

When you write only declaration `var a`, compiler does not know what to do with it. Is it an `object`? Maybe `string`? A number? How many memory to allocate on stack?

With a staticly typed language as `C#` if you declare a variable, state a type.
You can do it like this:

```
object data;
// rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `var` keyword you can use `dynamic` keyword. You can find more information on official MSDN site below:

[Dynamic Type C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

Some snippets from page:

> Visual C# 2010 introduces a new type, dynamic. The type is a static
>   type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking. In
>   most cases, it functions like it has type object. At compile time, an
>   element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to support any operation.

This is an alternative of var keyword. But I think you can do without dynamic by having condition in where clause as other answer mentioned on this page.

```
 .Where(a=> (a.EmployeeId != 0 && a.EmployeeId == employeeId) || your other conditions)
```